# replace chained filter / order pipes with functions Angular 8

Tags: angular, typescript

Now as per the [angular docs](https://angular.io/guide/pipes#appendix-no-filterpipe-or-orderbypipe)

> Filtering and especially sorting are expensive operations. The user experience can degrade severely for even moderate-sized lists when Angular calls these pipe methods many times per second. filter and orderBy have often been abused in AngularJS apps, leading to complaints that Angular itself is slow.

I have created a filter / order and search pipe in my application - originally performance wasnt an issue but now its causing some issues.

Basically in my application I have something like this

**component.html**

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let user of users | filter: filters | order: order | search: searchTerm"></li>
</ul>
```

**component.ts**

```
users = [
  {
    firstName: "Steve", 
    lastName: "Smith", 
    email: "test@test.com", 
    id: 102, 
    tags: [
      'newUser',
      'important',
      'funny'
    ]
  },
  {
    firstName: "James", 
    lastName: "Small", 
    email: "test2@test2.com", 
    id: 103,
    tags: [
      'important',
      'funny'
    ]
  },
  {
    firstName: "Peter", 
    lastName: "Salvadore", 
    email: "test3@test3.com", 
    id: 104,
    tags: [
      'newUser',
    ]
  }
];
```

now this does work well, but I am aware this isn't very performant

now my pipes look like this

**filter.pipe.ts**

```
// ...

public transform(value: User, tags: string[]) {
  if (value) {
    if (tags?.length > 0) {
      let users = [];
      tags.forEach(tag => {
        users = [...users, ...value.filter(x => x.tags.includes(tag))];
      });
      return users;
    } else {
      return value;
    }
  }
}
```

**order.pipe.ts**

```
// ...
public transform(value: User, order: string = 'firstName') {
  switch(order) {
    case 'firstName':
     return orderBy(value, ['firstName'], ['asc']);
    // ...
  }
}
```

etc.. now I want to move these pipes and create functions but my question is how can I chain them correctly to mimic how they work as chained pipes.

I think I could do something like this...

```
private USERS: Users = [ ... ];
public users: Users;
this.users = this.search(this.order(this.filter(this.USERS, filters), order), searchTerm);
```

but is that the best way?

Comment: it is much better performance wise to NOT use pipes. it's hard to say what to do in your use case without knowing how / when things like search, filter or order are set.

Comment: Is your pipe a pure pipe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit of research I came up with the following solution

I removed the pipes and created a helper class that chains all the functions together and returns the desired output

**sort-users.ts**

```
export class SortUsers {
   private _users: Users[];

   constructor(@Optional() users: Users[]) {
     this._users = users;
   }

   private search() {
     // ...
     return this;
   }

   private filter() {
     // ...
     return this;
   }

   private order() {
     // ...
     return this
   }

   public sort(users, searchTerm, filters, order) {
      const sort = new SortUsers(users);
      return sort
        .search(searchTerm)
        .filter(filters)
        .order(order)
   }
}
```

then in my component

```
private USERS: Users[];
users: Users[]

// ...

constructor(
  private _sort: SortUsers
) {}

// ...

sortUsers() {
   // ...
   this.users = this._sort(this._USERS, this.searchTerm, this.filters, this.order);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Every time one of the parameters is changed the entire chain of pipes has to be executed. You can avoid this side effect by splitting your pipes apart.

```html
 <ng-container *ngIf="users | filter: filters as filtered">
   <ng-container *ngIf="filtered | order: order as ordered">
      <ng-container *ngIf="ordered | search: searchTerm as searched">
         <li *ngFor="let user of searched"></li>
      </ng-container>
   </ng-container>
 </ng-container>
```

Only the relevant `<ng-container>` will be updated when `order` or `searchTerm` parameters are changed. The only condition here is that everything must yield a *truthy* value for the `*ngIf="xxx as yyy"` to work as expected. You should be okay with your example.